# Trying to parse JSON output in a Github Action

Tags: command-line-interface, jq, github-actions

I'm trying to extract the value of a HTTP request in a GitHub action and then use that value in another step.

This is the current code:

```
  - run: call some https endpoint
```

and that returns to the console output:

```
{
    "authorizationToken": "<snip>",
    "expiration": "2021-02-26T18:18:38+00:00"
}
```

and I'm trying to extract the `authorizationToken` value and then use it in the next step, like

```
  -name: Get auth token
   run: call some https endpoint
   
  -name: set something which uses the token
   run: set blah --token $token_from_previous_step
```

Now, I couldn't even get the value of the authentication Token extracted from the json output using the `jq` program:

```
~  - run: call some https endpoint | echo "jq '.authorizationToken'"~
```

which errors with:

```
jq '.authorizationToken'
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I'm now able to extract the key/value .. but not sure how to set it as an environment variable, to be used in other steps.

This works:

```
    - run: call some https endpoint > at.json
    - run: jq '.authorizationToken' at.json
```

so that get the json output from that https endpoint result and saves the result into a file called `at.json` (which is the json text, above).

Next, I then run the `jq` command, extracting the `authorizationToken` value. which works!

Now I need to set this value as a env-var. [Reading the docs on this, it looks like it can be done](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), but I'm not sure how to call `jq` and set the key/value into an env-var.

I feel like I need to do something like this:

```
    - run: echo "AUTH_TOKEN=run the jq command here" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Something like this (which totally fails):

```
    - run: echo "AUTH_TOKEN=${{ jq '.authorizationToken' at.json }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Why do you use `| echo "jq ..."` and not simply `| jq ...`?

Comment: Is the question about fixing the jq error or about passing value between steps/jobs?

Comment: @andlrc - because i was trying to get the output of the JQ result displayed to the screen as a "baby step" into getting the full answer. I couldn't even get that baby step, to work .. let alone get it extracted to some env var or whatever so other steps could use that value

Comment: @ITChap - it's about extracting the value and then being able to use that value on other steps. In this example, i was trying to leverage JQ as the way to extract the value (from a key) from the json, via a pipe. I couldn't even get that to work, let alone try the full solution.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Could you try the change that @andlrc mentioned? `call some https endpoint | jq '.authorizationToken'`. If this returns your token they I can write you a sample workflow to pass values around. Also if you could maybe give us the command used to call the endpoint. You can remove the url if it's sensitive.

Comment: I'll update the OP with what is working now and some new info I've learnt from the docs. WE CAN DO THIS! 

Comment: @ITChap - OP updated 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will just add here some more solutions. Like you discovered yourself, you can pass it as an environment variable:

```yaml
steps:
  - run: |
      token=$( callEndpoint | jq '.authorizationToken' )
      echo "AUTH_TOKEN=$token" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

    - run: echo "$AUTH_TOKEN"
```

You can also use a step output:

```yaml
steps:
  - id: get-token
    run: |
      token=$( callEndpoint | jq '.authorizationToken' )
      echo "::set-output name=auth_token::$token"

    - run: echo ${{ steps.get-token.outputs.auth_token }}
```

Both of these solutions will work for passing values between steps **of the same job**.

If you need to pass values between steps of different jobs, you can use job outputs:

```yaml
jobs:
  job-a:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      auth_token: ${{ steps.get-token.outputs.auth_token }}
    steps:
      - id: get-token
        run: |
          token=$( callEndpoint | jq '.authorizationToken' )
          echo "::set-output name=auth_token::$token"

  job-b:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job-a
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ needs.job-a.outputs.auth_token }}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I needed to use `>> $GITHUB_ENV` to set the environement variable.
- I needed to get the correct syntax to run a set of command line programs, inline.

```
    - run: call some https endpoint > at.json
    - run: echo "AUTH_TOKEN= $(jq '.authorizationToken' at.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - run: echo "${{ env.AUTH_TOKEN }}"
```

Details to the above solution:

- Line 1: some command which calls some external service via HTTPS. Response payload is JSON. this json data is then stored straight away into a file called `at.json`.
- Line 2: display some text in the format `<key>=<value>`. Then *append* this text to the github environment variable 'list/text/whatever'. Now -> here's the kicker => to calculate the `value` part of this key/value, run some command (or commands) inside this bit `$( .. )`. So for me, I'm running `jq` command and extracting the value of the `authorizationToken` from the json text, from inside the file `at.json`. Phew!
- Line3: just dump the value of my environment variable, to the log output. (yes, yes .. this is all insecure. I'm doing this as a test.)

and that's it!